# Grub doesn't show up when booting from usb

Tags: ubuntu, grub, ubuntu-14.04, usb-storage, portable-harddrive

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a portable HD. Unfortunately, it's only being recognized by the computer I used to install the Ubuntu os and it doesn't show the Grub menu when connecting the hd to other computers. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The GRUB menu shows up only if you put the HD as number one priority in the boot order settings. I had the same problem and I fixed it by doing that. If it doesn't show up anyways it's because you don't need it, there is only one OS on the HD. Grub is only useful for dual booting on the same disk.

Comment: GRUB is not “only useful for dual booting on the same disk”. You can set it up to boot from any disk, and also configure it to use specific options while booting.

Answer (score 0):

At startup the BIOS looks for a bootable disk in the sequence specified in the BIOS options. Typically this will first look at the drive inside the chassis. If that is already bootable (as it would be for almost every computer) it will simply boot from that, and not recognise your disk. If you want it to try your USB drive first you have to:

1. Plug in your disk
2. Start up the machine
3. Enter the BIOS configuration by pressing a key at start-up (typically one of the F keys on top of your keyboard)
4. Find what is typically called the “boot sequence” part of the configuration
5. Modify the sequence to put your disk at the top
6. Save and reboot

Caveat: The disk must be compatible with the PC. That includes *at least* the following off the top of my head:

- Supports the CPU architecture the disk was created for. Nowadays this is typically x86_64, as opposed to older 32-bit or ARM architectures.
- The BIOS configuration must either allow BIOS booting (as opposed to UEFI) or not have a setting for it.

Comment: The portable hd is already at the top of the list, it doesn't help